# How to force two separate words to be considered as just one in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing, overleaf, apa-style

I would like to change the following citation:
[image]

In particular, I would like to have the following instead:

The Economist (2022). White power and dark money. The Economist, 442(9282), 36.

This is my code in bibtex and I am using the apalike citation style:

```
@article{TheEconomist,
  author        = {Economist, The},
  title         = {White power and dark money},
  journal       = {The Economist},
  volume        = "\textbf{442}",
  number        = "9282",
  year          = "2022",
  pages         = "36"
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: `{{The Economist}}`

Comment: Thanks, Sigur. Yes, it works perfectly.

Comment: Note that generally it is not recommended to put formatting instructions like `\textbf` into the `.bib` file. The formatting should be handled by your bibliography style.